# Send variables from a python script run on a raspberry pi to webserver

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I have a python script running on my raspberry pi that outputs data from sensors connected to the pi's GPIO input. I need a simple way to have this live data on a server accessible from anywhere. I've looked at django framework but it seems like overkill for what I need to do.

Comment: very very quick and dirty way: use ngrok on raspberry itself to host files quickly over internet

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like [this?](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=35487&p=310038)

You can create a static webpage with some JS like so:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Pi</title>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="sensor1"></div>
    <a href="javascript:getSensor1()">Get data from sensor 1</a>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getSensor1() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "cgi-bin/cputemp.py",
                dataType: "html",
                success: function(msg) {
                    document.getElementById('sensor1').innerHTML = msg;
                },
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

And something like this in a `cgi-bin/cputemp.py` directory relative to your html page.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgi;
import cgitb;
import time
cgitb.enable()
import commands
import sys
import string
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
mytemp1 = commands.getoutput('/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp | cut -d "=" -f2 | cut -f1')
output = "Pi CPU Temp is: " + mytemp1
print output
```

Comment: Shouldn't `getSensor1()` be `cputemp2()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can run a script every x minutes with cron, the script will have to output the values instead of run in loops, and the cron task will be something like:

```
curl -X POST -d '$(python /path/to/script.py)' http://example.com/receive.php
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Flask** instead of Django.

And if you don't want to create server you can use third party Application Like [ThingSpeak](https://thingspeak.com/) where you can just post data and you can view your data from anywhere.